# Distribution of number of unique items in a sample

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Suppose we're sampling a discrete random variable from a distribution f, n times. Is there a simple analytical formulation for the expected number of unique items we obtain, or for the distribution of this number? Is there a name for this characteristic?

This question came up in a practical task: I have a stream of items arriving, every item having several Zipf-distributed parameters, and I'd like to answer queries like "how many items had a parameter equal to x" - I was wondering how feasible it is to just count each parameter value's occurrences (obviously, the space required is exactly what I'm asking about).

Comment: I found a similar question on math.stackexchange.com http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41519/expected-number-of-unique-items-when-drawing-with-replacement

Comment: The expected number of unique items is easy to calculate, using the linearity of expectation (exercise).

Comment: as to the algorithmic question: how accurate estimates do you want? a count-min sketch can give you estimates for each value within $\epsilon N$ additive error with probability $1-\delta$, where $N$ is the total number of items. the space requirement is $O(\log(1/\delta)\epsilon^{-1})$ words. the error is pretty miserable if you care about values that occur only a few times, but if you really only care about values that "dominate" the stream, it's good enough

Comment: @SashoNikolov - yes, I know, I can use approximations, but I'm wondering how far I can get with exact answers.